# php preg_match to get all js files url from body content

Tags: php, regex

Hi I trying to extract all .js files urls from a string fetched from html body mix of both html tags js and css.

for example :

```
<script src='https://www.example.com/bootstrap.min.js?c=-62170003800' type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="http://www.example.com/slick.js?c=-62170003800" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://example.com/jquery.scrollify.js?c=-62170003800" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>

    $.getScript('https://example.com/js/script.js', function()
    {
        // script is now loaded and executed.
        // put your dependent JS here.
    });
    </script>
```

now i want to get all java script files URLs as array

```
Array
(
    [0] => https://www.example.com/bootstrap.min.js
    [1] => http://www.example.com/slick.js
    [2] => http://www.example.com/slick.js 
    [3] => https://example.com/js/script.js
)
```

using `preg_match_all` as folloow

```
$jcotent = file_get_contents($file_name);
preg_match_all("`.*?((https|ftp)://[\w#$&+,\/:;=?@.-]+)[^\w#$&+,\/:;=?@.-]*?`i", $jcotent, $inner_files);
print_r($inner_files);
```

but instead of **`.*?((https|ftp)://[\w#$&+,\/:;=?@.-]+)[^\w#$&+,\/:;=?@.-]*?`i**

i want something more suitable like : we can use for image  **`/\< *[img][^\>]*[src] *= *[\"\']{0,1}([^\"\']*)/i`**

but i didn't figure out the matching pattern **regex** string please help me out

Comment: "_i want to_" is not a question. Please post the code you already have

Comment: Try using DOMDocument and loadHTML as it may give better results and be more consistent.

Comment: @kerbholz thank you  but  "i want to" is the gesture of defining my question any how thanks of letting me know new question asking pattern restrictions in stackoverflow

Comment: @SwarnaSekharDhar I put an answer and removed the comment! Glad it was of help:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex is not the means for parsing arbitrary html. However, instead of defining all the characters that the url could consist of, try by use of a [negated class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated). Further there is needless `.*?` preceding your pattern.

1. Look for a `'` or `"` followed by `https?`
2. Match as [few characters as possible](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution) that are neither `'` nor `"`  until `.js`

Adding optional white space and [resetting](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) before the desired part, the pattern is

```
[\"']\s*\Khttps?:[^\"']+?\.js
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/HTuZ5O/1) (escaped the double quote, as you use them for pattern).

Also be aware that your `[img]` pattern does not look like it would be working as desired. This is a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and it matches one character out of `i`,`m`,`g` same with `[src]`.